# How to give gradient ListView.builder items?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I have a listview.builder in my code and I have multiple widgets inside it. The problem is, that I have a list of numbers and I'm trying to make the gradient background of specific numbers. I only know starting index and length of the gradient background. But ListView.builder childrens building lazily. For example, I'm creating gradient numbers from 10th to 20th but it's not drawing if starting point is not showing in screen.

How can I show all colored/gradient numbers inside of ListView.builder? I don't want to use SingleChildScrollView and Column/Row, that may cause an performance issue. Is there any way to draw gradient items even if starting point not showing in screen?

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[Dartpad Example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=39a13be1b9bb64950315cb1a64f2edbd)

I have data like that

```
    final items = [
      for (var index = 1; index <= 30; index++)
        if (index == 10)
          DayType(
            value: index,
            type: GradientType.gradient,
          )
        else
          DayType(
            value: index,
            type: GradientType.common,
          )
    ];
```

and I'm trying to show inside of listView.

```
ListView.builder(
            controller: _scrollController,
            itemExtent: 40,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: (width - 40) / 2,
            ),
            itemCount: items.length,
            physics: _SnapScrollPhysics(
              itemSize: 40,
              onItemPositionUpdate: (index) {},
            ),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final item = items;

              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 2,
                ),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => _scrollToPosition(index),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      DayIndicator(
                        day: item[index],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
```

```
class DayIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  const DayIndicator({
    Key? key,
    required this.day,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final DayType day;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (day.type == GradientType.common) {
      return _CommonIndicator(
        day: day.value,
      );
    } else if (day.type == GradientType.gradient) {
      return _GradientIndicator(
        day: day.value,
        length: 8,
      );
    } else {
      throw Exception('Unknown type: ${day.type}');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you can  combine numberOfItems*(width+padding) for this I might choose to group the gradient item , itemcount /=numerOfGorups or Row with singleChildScrollView

Comment: Hi Yeasin, thanks for your answer. Row with singleChildScrollView might be a solution but that may cause a performance issue. On the other hand, if I group the gradients items, ListView.builder is only knows starting point again so if it's too long, listview can't show all items in list